# syntax error in my SQL Select Statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, inner-join

Getting error stating `between` operator without an `and` but I have an `and` so I don't understand. Thank you in advance

[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKPie.png)

[A picture of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3KLT.png)

```
select 
    a.student_name, a.test_score, b.letter_grade
from 
     sec1311_student_scores a 
inner join
     sec1311_grade_ranges b on a.testscore between b.beginning_score and b.endingscore
order by 
    a.student_name;
```

Comment: that's quite a strange syntax error message

Comment: That's some serious code-fu to achieve that message.  Are beginning_Score or ending_score null?  odd that one has a _ and one doesn't... are the "Scores" both numeric datatypes?  could you need to `coalesce(b.beginning_score,0) and coalesce(b.endingscore,0)`? or should the last score always be 100 or something?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Some (like maybe Access) may want the `z BETWEEN x AND y` clause to be enclosed in parentheses `(z BETWEEN x AND y)`

Comment: should the ON statement link student_scores and grade_ranges?

Comment: Yes i am using access and the datatypes are numbers

Answer (score 2):

Access does not support `BETWEEN` in join clauses.  From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197346.aspx):

```
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 compopr table2.field2
The INNER JOIN operation has these parts:

Part           | Description 
----           | -------------
table1, table2 | The names of the tables from which records are combined.
field1, field2 | The names of the fields that are joined. If they are not numeric, the fields must be of the same data type and contain the same kind of data, but they do not have to have the same name.
compopr        | Any relational comparison operator: "=," "<," ">," "<=," ">=," or "<>."
```

You can, however, specify *multiple* join conditions, so you should be able to do:

```
select 
    a.student_name, a.test_score, b.letter_grade
from 
     sec1311_student_scores a 
inner join
     sec1311_grade_ranges b on a.testscore >= b.beginning_score 
                        and on a.testscore <= b.endingscore
order by 
    a.student_name;
```

Comment: You are right Access doesnt support BETWEEN in the ON clause.  And just for the sake of being accurate : this is usually called a [non equi-join](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-non-equi-join.php)

Comment: it doesnt work still with the new code either. but thanks for the info on the between

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
select 
    a.student_name, a.test_score, b.letter_grade
from 
    sec1311_student_scores as a, 
    sec1311_grade_ranges as b 
where
    a.testscore between b.beginning_score and b.ending_score
order by 
    a.student_name;
```

Comment: That works but i was asked to write what you just wrote with a inner join instead of the where clause. Thank you for your effort though it is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can be asked many things, sometimes the impossible but, in Access SQL, this is the method. It is even displayable in the GUI designer which some join methods not are.